# Wake-On-Lan does not work after shutdown -f command

Tags: linux, debian, wake-on-lan

I have a Debian server and each time I shutdown with `poweroff -f` command, the Wake-On-Lan is not working. How can I use `poweroff` command without losing the Wake-On-Lan functionality?

Comment: Why are you doing `-f` with `poweroff`?  How do you know the wake-on-lan is not working?  What does the log say?

Comment: @tukan I am using `-f` because my machine does not shutdown otherwise. I know it's not working because I test it. So when I am using `poweroff -f` command then I can't power on the machine with Wake-On-Lan. But when I am using `shutdown` command then I can power on with Wake-On-Lan

Comment: I managed to fix the issue. I had to use the `ethtool` to enable Wake-On-Lan before executing the `poweroff` command.

Comment: So please anser your own question and accept it.